# More comments overlapping add comment on the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

On any question or answer with many comments the *Show more comments* button is partly hidden by the *Add comment* button. I'm on a [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II) if it matters.

Example question: [Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in version v0.1.10 and should be hitting devices soon.

Comment: Yes I can see its resolved in 0.1.10 version.