# Add comment button overlapping the view more comments link

Tags: bug, android-app

App version: 1.0.21

Device: Huawei Ascend G510 (running Android 4.1.1)

Problem: When viewing a question, if there are comments the link to click to view more comments is being overlapped by the Add comment button (picture below).

This was reported on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192945/more-comments-overlapping-add-comment-on-the-stack-exchange-android-app) question and was resolved, but it is happening again.

[image: Add comment button overlapping the view more comments]